# C#での文字コード変換に関して

Tags: c#, 文字コード

お世話になります。
ものすごい初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、教えていただけると幸いです。
まず、サンプルソースです。
申し訳ないですが、usingとかいろいろ省略してしまってます。

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
sb.Append("テスト"+i);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

上記のように取得した文字列をUTF-8やShift_Jis等に変換したいのですが、どうすればよいのでしょうか。
文字列をバイト型配列に変換すればいいとは思うんですが、string型のエンコードって何になるんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Encoding.GetBytes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_)で`string`からバイト型配列に変換できます。
UTF-8については[`Encoding.UTF8`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=netframework-4.8)で得られますが、Shift_JISについては[`Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis")`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_GetEncoding_System_String_)で得られます。

なおC#言語の`string`は`System.String`のエイリアスであり、`System.String`はUTF-16となっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。stringはUTF-16なんですね。大変助かりました。